# Узнать есть ли запись в таблице mysql или нет

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, if

Есть таблица:

```
id   url

1    link1
2    link2
3    link3
```

Делаем запрос и если совпадение есть, то делаем одно, если ответ false, то делаем другое. Но сами данные не нужны, нужно узнать только результат поиска нашли/не нашли.

```
$sql  = "SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `url` = 'link2'";

if (совпадение есть, то) {
     echo "+";
} else {
     echo "-";
}
```

Как правильно составить запрос на php?

Comment: Может стоит использовать `COUNT` https://sql-language.ru/sql-count.html

Comment: Запрос надо выполнить сначала, а не просто в переменную текст записать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так сделать запрос:

```
select exists(select FROM `table` where url = 'link2')
```

Тогда будет возвращаться `true` или `false`